# Enabling a disabled input type image is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Dears , i am trying to enable a disabled input type image based on some conditions
i tried several codes with no solution
i am using angular js and jQuery , any idea how to solve this issue

HTML

```
<td style="width: 46px;">
<a href="#">
<input type="image" ng-click="committeeedit() ;$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();" src="assets/images/pencil.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<input disabled type="image" id="deleteCommitteeBtn" ng-click="deleteCommittee()" ng-src="assets/images/cross.png" />
</a>
</td>
```

```
setenabledfields();
        function setenabledfields() {
            cmePointsSrv.getSecurity("CMEpoints/getSecurity?hospkey=" + $scope.hospitalid).then(function (response) {
                $scope.Security = (response.data);
                //console.log($scope.Security);
               

                if ($scope.Security[0].code == 1) {
                    cmePointsSrv.getenabledfields("CMEpoints/getenabledfields?funckey=" + $scope.funckey + '&staffkey=' + $scope.staffkey).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.enabledfields = (response.data);

                        $('#frame input,#frame select').attr('disabled', 'true');
                        
                        $scope.enabledfields.forEach(function (e) {
                            var tt = document.getElementById(e.ctrl_Actual_name.split('.')[1])

                            if (tt != null) {
                                //console.log(tt);
                                document.getElementById(e.ctrl_Actual_name.split('.')[1]).disabled = false;
                            }
                            //else { document.getElementById(e.ctrl_Actual_name.split('.')[1]).disabled = true;}

                        })
                    })
                } else {
                   

                        //document.getElementById("deleteMeetingBtn").disabled = true; 
                        //document.getElementById("deleteCompulsoryBtn").disabled = true; 
                        //document.getElementById("deleteTrainingBtn").disabled = true; 
                        //document.getElementById("deleteOtherBtn").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("deleteCommitteeBtn").disabled = false;
                    //$("#deleteCommitteeBtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //$("#deleteCommitteeBtn").prop("disabled", true);
                    $("deleteCommitteeBtn").removeAttr('disabled');
                    //$("#deleteCommitteeBtn")[0].onclick = null;
                }

            })
        }
```

Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Seems weird you would be doing this with jQuery and not angular

Comment: thanks for replying i tried both with no solution unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

$('#deleteCommitteeBtn').prop('disabled', 'false');

Comment: Add this code to brovser console: $('#deleteCommitteeBtn'); and press enter, then look the DOM where is pointing. Maybe is another id line this or the DOM is created after

Comment: context: document
selector: "#deleteCommitteeBtn"